# float 2 elements left and have the right one on top?

Tags: css

I have the following CSS and HTML:

```css
 .row {
   width: 100%;
 }
 .col {
   float: left;
   width: 45%;
 }
 @media screen and (max-width: 1300px) {
   .col {
     width: 100%;
   }
 }
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    left
  </div>
  <!-- /.col -->
  <div class="col">
    right
  </div>
  <!-- /.col -->
</div>
<!-- /.row -->
```

It works as expected when the screen is less 1300px they collapse with the left one on top of the right; how do I make the right one end up on top of the left one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either have a look at using Flexbox, or tell them to float right in the media query

```
.col {
    float: left;
    width: 45%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1300px) {
    .col {
        width: 100%;
        float: right;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use display:table and table-header-group:

```css
.row {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.col {
  display: table-cell;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1300px) {
  .col {
    display: block;
  }
  .col + .col {
    display: table-header-group;
    background: gray;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    left
  </div>
  <!-- /.col -->
  <div class="col">
    right
  </div>
  <!-- /.col -->
</div>
<!-- /.row -->
```

or flex

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}
.col {
  flex: 1;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1300px) {
  .row {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .col {
    order: 1;
  }
  .col + .col {
    order: 0;
    background: gray
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    left
  </div>
  <!-- /.col -->
  <div class="col">
    right
  </div>
  <!-- /.col -->
</div>
<!-- /.row -->
```

Comment: i missunderstood the question obviously :)  ... or not